# make a function that Calculates total GPA

Tags: javascript

okay so im suppose to take in an array of grades and then calculate the GPA. It keeps coming up as "Nan" and i forget how to change that... I also don't think my GPA variable is correct.
"The function must take in one parameter that will contain an array of letter grades (for example, ["A+", "A-", "C", "B-", "A"])
The funciton must find the current GPA"

```
 var letter = "";
 var GPA;

 function calculateTotalGPA(letter) {
     var counter = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
         if (letter == "A+") {
             GPA = 4;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "A") {
             GPA = 4;
             counter++;

         }
         if (letter == "A-") {
             GPA = 3.67;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "B+") {
             GPA = 3.33;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "B") {
             GPA = 3;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "B-") {
             GPA = 2.67;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "C+") {
             GPA = 2.33;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "C") {
             GPA = 2;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "C-") {
             GPA = 1.67;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "D") {
             GPA = 1;
             counter++;
         }
         if (letter == "F") {
             GPA = 0;
             counter++;
         }
     }
     return (GPA / counter);
 }
```

Comment: consider using an array...

Comment: consider using a switch case.

Comment: The letter.length can be save to a variable.

Comment: @Mark What's the exact meaning of `totalGPA` and `currentGPA`?

Comment: I suggest that you step away from the computer and figure out how to do the calculations by hand. For example, if you get an A, B+, and B, what is the GPA? If you can do this by hand, you will have an easier time figuring out what you have done wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to write this code but I think it's more useful to show what's wrong with your current code as opposed to suggesting something completely different.

In your if statements you're checking whether `letter` is equal to a string but `letter` is an array of strings, so you want to check the element at index `i` of your loop.

i.e. change

```
if (letter == "A+") {
```

to

```
if (letter[i] == "A+") {
```

You want to count the total GPA points before you divide by `counter` but currently you reset GPA at each iteration.

change

```
 GPA = 4;
```

to

```
 GPA = GPA + 4;
```

or shorthand

```
 GPA += 4;
```

also initialize the variable before you enter the for loop

```
 var GPA = 0;
```

As mentioned in the comments there are other things you can do to optimize your code.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! I always seem to be fairly close on all of my codes and then just forgetting a few minor aspects that screw me over

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to offer a few recommendations, first I do not see the point in your `for` statement, it has not bearing in the calculation. The scope of the variables `letter` and `GPA` seems odd to have these 2 outside the scope of the calculation function, probably it is better to move at least `GPA` declaration inside the calculation function.

About the calculation function itself my recommendation is to create a JSON objects and use it like a "Dictionaries", which is like a `key` `value` object, for example:

```
var GPAs = {
   "A" : 4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3,"B-":2.67,"C+":2.33,"C":2,"C-":1.67,"D":1,"F":0
};
```

Then you can access them like arrays using `letter`:

```
var GPA =  GPAs[letter] ;
```

Your whole function will look like:

```
function calculateGPA(letter) {
    var GPAs = {
       "A" : 4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3,"B-":2.67,"C+":2.33,"C":2,"C-":1.67,"D":1,"F":0
    };
   return GPAs[letter];
}
```

To get the total from an array, there are various ways to achieve this and one is using `Array.prototype.reduce`, for example :

```
["A", "A"].reduce(function(a,letter){ 
         a=a+calculateGPA(letter); return a;
},0);
```

Reducing the `calculateGPATotal` function to something like:

```
function calculateGPATotal(arrayOfLetters){
     var GPAs = {
       "A" : 4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3,"B-":2.67,"C+":2.33,"C":2,"C-":1.67,"D":1,"F":0
    };
     return arrayOfLetters.reduce(function(a,letter){  a=a+GPAs[letter]; return a;},0) / arrayOfLetters.length;
  }
```

Please note that I am using `arrayOfLetters.length` instead of `counter` which seemed to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Almost right but his input is an array and he needs to compute the average GPA based on his current code, I think the counter is needed, and need to loop throught the array letter since OP described in input as an array of letter grades

Comment: @andrex I updated the answer correcting this overlooked detail about the array.

Comment: A very advance answer, it's confusing for beginner but if it does the job I'll vouch for it.